# Consecutive numbers question.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is , $6n-5$ and $5n+3$ are two consecutive whole numbers. What are all the possible values for $n$ ?

The workings out said that we dont't know which number is bigger so we form two equations

$$(6n-5)-(5n+3)=1\tag{1}$$
$$(5n+3)-(6n-5)=1\tag{2}$$

Then go on to working out all the  possible values for $n$.

However my question is that how can $6n-5$ be bigger than $5n+3$ .
How can this happen because İ think that $5n+3$ is bigger than $6n-5$.

Comment: Well, it depends on $n$.  If $n=2$ then you are right!  $5n+3=13$ while $6n-5=7$.  However, if $n=9$ you are wrong, as $5n+3=48$ but $6n-5=49$.

Comment: Thabk you , so how can İ logically explain that we don't know which number is bigger. İs there some sort of proof?

Comment: My two examples are a proof.  But...so what?  You don't need to know this going in.  Your method is good.  Starting out, you can't be sure you'll get a solution to one or the other equation, but as it happens you get one solution for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I would distinguish two cases:
$$6n -5=m$$
$$5n+3=m+1$$ from here we get $$m=37$$

or

$$5n+3=m$$
$$6n-5=m+1$$
so we get

$$m=48$$

Comment: Lol i feel dumb now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your Problem solved now?

Comment: Yes thank you İ will tick you question when it let's me .

Answer (score 2):

If we subtract $(5n+3)-(6n-5)$ we get $8-n$.  This is positive for $n \lt 8$, so in those cases $5n+3$ is larger.  It is negative for $n \gt 8$ so in those cases $6n-5$ is larger.

Comment: Also a very logical answer thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the  possibility of $6n-5$ being greater than $5n+3$ only if we *know* that it is never true. As long as it is not proved, all possibilities must be taken into account, and in the process, it can happen that some cases are discarded for providing no solutions. If some possibilities are initially ignored, there is a chance that some solutions are missed.

In general, if we want to check if there is any $n$ for which $6n-5 \gt 5n+3$, we can simply solve
$$6n-5 \gt 5n+3 \implies n \gt 8$$

So, such cases do exist. Similarly, it can be seen that for $n\le 8$, we have $5n+3\ge 6n-5$. Since you need to find all possible values of $n$, you need to take both cases into account. Of course, your method of solving could involve taking two cases where $n\le 8$ and $n\gt 8$, and the information of which of $6n-5$ and $5n+3$ is greater from the above result.

Answer (score 1):

We need

- $(6n-5)-(5n+3)=1$

or

- $(5n+3)-(6n-5)=1$

in the first case we have

- $(6n-5)-(5n+3)=n-8=1 \implies n=9$

in the second case

- $(5n+3)-(6n-5)=-n+8=1 \implies n=7$